# Actionscript web service and web method call classes

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to isolate a webservice in its own class, and I plan to add separate classes to each webmethod there is in the webservice.  What I have so far works, but I have this feeling tickling that I've missed something (except for the invisible variable declarations down here, I didn't want to clog the page).

Webservice instantiation class and its fault handler:

```
 public class CfdWS
        {

            [Bindable] 
            private var model:ModelLocator = ModelLocator.getInstance();

            public function loadWebService():WebService{
                var webService : WebService = new WebService();
                webService.wsdl = model.configXML.cfdwsWSDL;
                webService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, onWebServiceFault);
                webService.loadWSDL();
                return webService;
            }

            private function onWebServiceFault(event:FaultEvent):void{
                var fault: Fault = event.fault;
                var message:String = "\ncodigo: " + fault.faultCode;
                message += "\nDetalle: " + fault.faultDetail;
                Alert.show("Error de webservice:" + message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The following is my webservice method call class. I have written only what I think is the essential code for the question.

```
public class GeneratePDF extends CfdWS{

    public function generatePDF():void{
                webService = loadWebService();
                webService.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD, doGeneratePDF);
            }
            private function doGeneratePDF(event:LoadEvent):void{
                webService.generatePDF.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, generatePDFResultHandler);
                webService.generatePDF(pdfData);
            }
            private function generatePDFResultHandler (event:ResultEvent):void{
                // After getting what I want, I remove the event listeners here.
            }
}
```

I'm trying to re-write an application that is already in production while on testing phase (testing for the next version I mean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why would you put every method of the service in a separate class. A "method" is a function of the class. I imagine you wanted to decouple your code, but doing it this way you will force a lot of overhead:

- the service is instantiated for every 'method' called, and then, hopefully, garbage collected (as you remove event listeners and there's no more references to the service left)
- because of above, the service is stateless; with time you may want to add some functionality like caching, but you'd need to change whole code structure for that
- CfdWS - not descriptive name; your way of decoupling code will force you to make three or even five times more classes then you normally would, so I would expect a hell on the file-naming level
- really, dividing to so many classes is not a good idea - you don't want to switch between files all the time; try to put related code in one Class, and if it grows big, create some helper classes

I think you already understand the benefit of a good MVC implementation, try Robotlegs, it really makes a life easier:
http://www.robotlegs.org/